# How to automatically populate value from action class to the JSP TextBox

Tags: struts2

I am able to print value from Java Action Class to JSP Page without textbox, But when I want to put that value in a TextBox in JSP, its not coming.
My Code is :

```
<S:form>
<s:textfield name="toDate" key="td"  > <s:property  value="fromDate"/> </s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="fromDate" key="fd"> <s:property value="toDate" /> </s:textfield>
<s:submit value="Confirm"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

toDate and fromDate is variables in Java Class.

Answer (score 0):

Just dive in the [Struts2 UI Tag documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ui-tag-reference.html):

> **key** : Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component

If you want them different (eg. `toDate` the value to set, `td` the value to read, and so on), specify all of them:

```
<s:form>
    <s:textfield name="toDate"   value="td" label="To date"   /> 
    <s:textfield name="fromDate" value="fd" label="From date" /> 
    <s:submit value="Confirm" />
</s:form>
```

(Obviously according to your getters and setters).

Answer (score 0):

You can set value in TextBox using value attribute of `<s:textfield>` tag to value come from action class.
For this you have your getter and setter method for that variable in action class and read that value by below code:
For Example :

```
<s:textfield name="some_name" value="%{variable}"/>
```

your code look like this:

```
<s:form>
    <s:textfield name="toDate"   value="%{fromDate}"  /> 
    <s:textfield name="fromDate" value="%{toDate}" /> 
    <s:submit value="Confirm" />
</s:form>
```